# Parse only time, and set date to today?

Tags: python

I am trying to convert a time string into a `datetime` object where the date is today's date. However, I only have a time string and its `replace()` method does not seem to work.

```
from datetime import datetime, time,date
timestr = "9:30"
startTime = datetime.strptime(timestr,"%H:%M")
startTime.replace(year=datetime.now().year, month=datetime.now().month, day=datetime.now().day)
print startTime
>>> 1900-01-01 09:30:00
```

I want:

```
2017-01-20 09:30:00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`replace` doesn't work in-place. Don't ignore the return value, assign it back like this:

```
startTime = startTime.replace(year=datetime.now().year, month=datetime.now().month, day=datetime.now().day)
```

and you get:

```
2017-01-20 09:30:00
```

Comment: funny: I did _not_ read the documentation. It's such a classical error anyone can make, but it doesn't mean that some `replace` calls for other modules don't work in-place. It depends on the interface.

Answer (score 3):

nicer than `replace` is `combine`:

```
timestr = "9:30"
startTime = datetime.strptime(timestr,"%H:%M")
d = datetime.combine(datetime.today(), startTime.time())
```

Comment: this is specifically done for this use case, and it removes the multiple calls to `now()` or `today()`

Comment: thanks. I've taken the other comment as answer because it directly addresses the .replace issue. However, I used ur answer in my code. Thanks very much

Answer (score -1):

Here is another solution using another library.

```
import pendulum
timestr = "9:30"
dt = pendulum.parse(timestr)
<Pendulum [2017-01-20T09:30:00+00:00]>
```

Or

```
dt = pendulum.parse(timestr).to_datetime_string()
'2017-01-20 09:30:00'
```