# How to read a text as today's time in python?

Tags: python, datetime

When I try to convert a string that contains some time in the format of 13:00, it is keeping the date field as **1900-01-01** 13:00:00.

But I want to keep today's' date there.

```
import datetime as dt
sTime = "13:00"
sTime = dt.datetime.strptime(sTime, '%H:%M')
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse only time, and set date to today?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41772061/parse-only-time-and-set-date-to-today)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`combine`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.combine):

```
import datetime as dt

sTime = "13:00"
sTime = dt.datetime.strptime(sTime, '%H:%M')
print(dt.datetime.combine(dt.datetime.today(), sTime.time()))
```

outputs

```
2020-08-28 13:00:00
```

Or directly but with a bit more work:

```
import datetime as dt

sTime = "13:00"
sTime = dt.datetime.strptime(sTime, '%H:%M')
today = dt.datetime.today()
print(dt.datetime(today.year, today.month, today.day, sTime.hour, sTime.minute, sTime.second))
```

Comment: I have a list which contains times like this ['13:45','12:30','11:40']. In string format.So, the script should pick the least time in the string format list and wait till that time occurs.

The first part I got using min function after converting the date using the code you provided, but how to make it wait till that time?

Comment: @udaykiran that is an entirely different question. Please ask it as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime as dt

sTime = "13:00"

# PARSE string to datetime object
objDateTime = dt.datetime.strptime(sTime, "%H:%M")

# combine PARSED time from sTime with today's date
objDateTime = dt.datetime.combine(dt.datetime.today(), objDateTime.time())
                          
# FORMAT objDateTime to Hr:Min string output
print(objDateTime.strftime("%H:%M"))

# FORMAT objDateTime to DD-MMM-YYYY Hr:Min string output
print(objDateTime.strftime("%d-%b-%Y %H:%M"))
```

**Output (when run on 28-Aug-2020)**

```
13:00
28-Aug-2020 13:00
```